# DTEXEC SQL Server 2012 Timeout After 30 Seconds

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

When running the following command on a SQL Server 2012:

```
dtexec /isserver "\My Folder\My Package.dtsx" /X86 /SERVER "." /REPORTING V /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED (Boolean)";True
```

We received the following error after 30 seconds every time:

```
Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904. Server: ., Package path: \My Folder\My Package.dtsx, Environment reference Id: NULL.
Description: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Started:  1:57:04 PM
Finished: 1:57:35 PM
Elapsed:  30.311 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra space between **"SYNCHRONIZED"** and **"(Boolean)"**. Removing this extra space resolved the error. The error message didn't point us to this problem, so we learned through trial and error over several hours. The command should read:

```
dtexec /isserver "\My Folder\My Package.dtsx" /X86 /SERVER "." /REPORTING V /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True
```

And we no longer see the timeout error.